# LGBMClassifier create_tree_diagraph not showing in notebook

Tags: python, lightgbm

I am using LightGBM's LGBMClassifier for a binary classification problem and want to print out the actual diagram.

Here is how I trained/fit the model

```
clf = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train, categorical_feature = x_train.select_dtypes(include = 'category').columns.tolist())
```

And here is how I am trying to print the diagram

```
lgb.create_tree_digraph(clf, orientation='vertical')
```

However, the only output I am getting is

```
<graphviz.graphs.Digraph at 0x7f6a10a5ed00>
```

I also tried using the parent lightgbm.train() method to build the model and as the booster argument in create_tree_diagraph, however I am getting similar output.

Is there an additional library or function I have to call to print out the tree, or is there another way to perhaps save it to a .png file?

I am using a Python Notebook in Databricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REPL explained to you that you have a Digraph in hand.
Good. Let's assign it to a temp var, and render it.

https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#basic-usage

```
g = lgb.create_tree_digraph( ... )

g.render(view=True)

g.format = "png"
g.render("output.png")

g.view()
```

This relies on `dot` being already installed
so it works when bash invokes it.

Comment: Is it possible to install dot in databricks notebook - is it just %pip install dot?

Comment: In [some](https://packages.debian.org/buster/graphviz) environments it will be `apt install graphviz`. But don't take my word for it. There is [extensive](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/install.html#extra-packages) [documentation](https://graphviz.org/download).